# Javascript test : Selenium cookies data url

Tags: javascript, selenium, cookies, behat

I have a Behat test running Selenium whenever Javascript is needed.
My current Behat test works just fine if Javascript (so Selenium is disable).

At the moment, my only error feedback from Selenium is the following statement :

```
unknown: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
        (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.2.0-16-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
      Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
      System info: host: 'ca7a41afbfee', ip: '172.17.0.10', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-16-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45-internal'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
      Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.WWmJvH}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=48.0.2564.109, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
      Session ID: b8a3f435fe337ca77d523d5b72f6235b (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Some posts talk about cookies but I don't really see where to append them.

Answer (score 10):

You can't set a cookie using the Chrome driver until the page is fully loaded. Use selenium to wait for the page to load and then set cookies.

Comment: Finally, I switch from Selenium to [Nightwatch.js](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch), all clear since.

Answer (score 3):

You will need open page before add cookie:

```
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
$this->urnOpen('/');
$cookie = array();
$cookie['name'] = 'NAME';
$cookie['value'] = 'VALUE';
$this->webDriver->manage()->addCookie($cookie);
```